# 'throw' of exception caught locally - Code duplication or warnings

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

I know, that there is already few threads about this, but I am very courious what is more correct in this example:

```js
// This is not correct and showing "'throw' of exception caught locally" warning
function test1(input: any): boolean {
  try {
    if (!input)
      throw new Error("You not set test variable.");
    
    const number: int = parseInt(input); // This can throw exception too
    
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error: ", err);
    return false;
  }
}
 
 
// This is correct, but it is larger code and code duplication
function test2(input: any): boolean {
  try {
    if (!input){
      console.error("Error: You not set test variable.");
      return false;
    }
    
    const number: int = parseInt(input); // This can throw exception too
    
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error: ", err);
    return false;
  }
}
```

As you can see `test1()` will cause warning in most IDEs and it is not optimized by compiler, but there is no code duplication and excessive lines.

I think this is not opinion based question, because then IDE will not warn you about using first example.

Comment: An IDE is right to warn you - do not use exceptions as flow control, it's extremely bad practice. The "duplication" of half a line of code is trivial and not something worth bothering about. If you're super bothered by this "waste", then you can also save a line by not having that many `return` statements and that should more than balance things out.

Comment: Relevant: [Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222)

Comment: In addition, the design of this function is flawed. Either the function should throw or it should return [but cannot do both](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw).